# Kasparov's Dirac element and the index map

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory, rt.representation-theory, noncommutative-geometry

In Kasparov's 1988 paper [Equivariant KK-theory and the Novikov conjecture](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01404917) section 4 he defined the Dirac element for a (non-spin) $G$- Riemanian manifold $X$ as an element in the $K$-homology $K^0_G(C_{\tau}(X))=KK^G(C_{\tau}(X),\mathbb{C})$, where $C_{\tau}(X)$ is the algebra of continuous sections vanishing at infinity of the complex Clifford bundle on $X$.

In more details, let $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\bigwedge^*(X))$ be the Hilbert space of $L^2$-forms on $X$.  $ C_{\tau}(X) $ acts on $ \mathcal{H}=L^2(\bigwedge ^ * (X)) $  (from the left) by the usually Clifford multiplication. Let $d$ be the exterior derivation and $d^*$ be its adjoint using the Riemanian structure on $X$. $\mathcal{D}:=d+d ^ * $. Of course $\mathcal{D}$ is not bounded but there exits an operator $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{D}(1+\mathcal{D}^2)^{-1/2}\in L(\mathcal{H})$. The pair $(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{F})$ gives the Dirac element $[d_X]\in K^0_G(C_{\tau}(X))=KK^G(C_{\tau}(X),\mathbb{C})$.

If $X$ has a $G$-equivariant $\text{spin}^{c}$ structure, there exists a vector bundle $S$ on $X$ such that $C_{\tau}(X)=\text{End}(S)$ hence $C_{\tau}(X)$ is Morita equivalent to $C_0(X)$, the algebra of continuous functions on $X$ vanishing at infinity. Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of the $L^2$ sections of $S$ and $D$ denote the Dirac operator on $S$ and $F:=D(1+D^2)^{-1/2}\in L(H)$. $(H,F)$ gives an element in $K^{\dim X}_G(C_0(X))=KK^G_{\dim X}(C_0(X),\mathbb{C})$. It can be proved that under the Morita equivalence $C_{\tau}(X)\sim C_0(X)$, $(H,F)$ represents the same element as $(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{F})$ in the last paragraph (The main reason is that $d+d^* $ and $D$ have the same principal symbol). This justifies the name "Dirac element"  for $[d_X]=(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{F})$ in the last paragraph.

We also have the descent homomorphism
$$
\phi: KK^G(C_0(X),\mathbb{C})\rightarrow KK(C^ * _r (G; C_0(X)), C^ * _r (G))
$$
hence $\phi([d_X]) \in KK(C^ * _r (G; C_0(X)), C^ * _r (G))$.

Now if we defined the equivariant K-theory $ K^ G _n (X) $ to be $K_0(C^ * _r (G; C_0(X\times\mathbb{R}^ n)))$ where $C^ * _r (G; C_0(X\times \mathbb{R}^ n))$ is the  reduced cross product $C^∗$-algebra. It can be verified that when $G$ is compact, this definition coincide with the original equivariant K-theory given by Atiyah and Segal. We now use the element $\phi([d_X]) \in KK( C ^ * _ r(G;C_0(X)),C^*_ r(G))$ in the last paragraph and through the right multiplication in Kasparov product it gives a map
$$
K^G_{i+\dim X}(X) \rightarrow K^ G_i(pt)
$$
In fact more generally it give a map $K^G_{i+\dim X}(X\times Y)\rightarrow K^G_i(Y)$ for any space $Y$ and $i=0,1$ when $X$ is $\text{spin}^{c}$ .

On the other hand, notice that when $ U < G $ is the maximal compact subgroup of $G$, if $X=G/U$ and $Y= pt$, we can define the index map
$$
K^G_{i+\dim G/U}(G/U)\rightarrow K^G_i(pt)
$$
in the statement of Connes-Kasparov conjecture, whether $X=G/U$ is $\text{spin}^{c}$ or not, see Penington and Plymen's 1983 paper [The Dirac operator and the principal series for complex semisimple Lie groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123683900356).

Let me say more words about their construction and the relation to ours (thanks for the comments of Alain Valette). By definition $K^G_0(G/U)=K_0(C^*_r(G;C_0(G/U)))$ and $C^*_r(G;C_0(G/U))$ is Strong Morita equivalent to $ C^*_r(U)$. Since $U$ is compact, $K_0(C^*_r(U))=R(U)$  the representation ring of $U$ hence $K^G_0(G/U)=K_0(C^*_r(U))=R(U)$  and similarly $K^G_1(G/U)=K_1(C^*_r(U))=0$. In Penington-Plymen paper the index map is defined to be
$$
R(U)\rightarrow K _ {\dim G/U}(C^*_r(G))
$$
using the index map of the Dirac operator when $G/U$ is $\text{spin}^{c}$. When $G/U$ is not $\text{spin}^{c}$, they use the double covering of $G$ and then do the similar construction.

My question is: if $X$ is not $\text{spin}^{c}$, can we also use the Dirac element $[d_X]$ to give a index map $K^G_{i+\dim X}(X\times Y)\rightarrow K^G_i(Y)$?

Comment: First, I think that you should be more specific about the properties you expect of an index map. Second, I checked the Penington-Plymen paper and there is no mention of the index map you indicate; their index map goes from the representation ring $R(U)$ to the K-theory $K_*(C^*_r(G))$ of the reduced $C^*$-algebra of $G$.

Comment: @Alain: Thank you for your comments! Sure I should be more clear about what I want. The second point you made may be because of the non-standard terminology I used. In fact for any Lie group $G$ I define $K^G_0(X)=K(C_r^*(G; C_0(X)))$ where $C_r^*(G; C_0(X))$ is the reduced cross product $C^*$-algebra. Hence the $K_*(C^*_r(G))$ is exactly $K^G_*(pt)$ in my question. As for $R(U)$, since $U$ is compact, $R(U)=K_0(C^*_r(U))$. We also notice that $C^*_r(U)$ is strong Morita equivalent to $C^*_r(G; C_0(G/U))$, hence $R(U)=K^G_0(G/U)$ in this context. The index map I am looking for is the same as 

Comment: @Alain: (Continued) The index map I am looking for is the same as that in Penington-Plymen paper.

I apologize for the confusing I've made and I have made some modifications in the question body to define equivariant K-theory more clearly. Nevertheless it is really appreciated that you pointed out the problem. 

Comment: @Zhaoting: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I think however that you should write $K^n_G(X)$ rather than $K^G_n(X)$, because it is K-theory, i.e. a theory contravariant in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question completely, but let me try something. Since the Clifford algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is unital, you have an inclusion $i:C_0(X)\rightarrow C_\tau(X)$ (sections which are pointwise multiples of the unit), which you may use to pull-back $[d_X]$, so you have $i^*[d_X]\in KK^0_G(C_0(X),\mathbb{C})$; then you may apply amplification $\tau_Y: KK^0_G(C_0(X),\mathbb{C})\rightarrow KK^0_G(C_0(X\times Y),C_0(Y))$, then the descent map $\phi$, you get an element in $KK_0(C_0(X\times Y)\rtimes G,C_0(Y)\rtimes G)$, and right Kasparov product with this element gives you a map $K^*_G(X\times Y)\rightarrow K^*_G(Y)$ - with no shift of dimension however.